Как тестировать QThread в gtest?
Пытаюсь запускаю в потоке функцию doWork()
#include <QObject>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QThread>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets>

#include <QWaitCondition>


#include <QApplication>


#include <QDebug>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    void doWork() {
        QThread::sleep(2); // имитируем долгий процесс вычислений в потоке
        emit resultReady("Workers are the best");
    }
  signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &data);
};


class Client : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client() {}
    virtual ~Client() {}
    QString data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

public slots:
    void append(const QString& data) {
        m_data = data;
        qDebug() << data;
    }

private:
    QString m_data;
};

int main()
{
    int argc1 = 0;
    QCoreApplication app(argc1, (char**)0);

    /* Setup thread */
    Client wgt;
    auto thread = new QThread(&wgt);
    auto worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, &wgt, &Client::append);

    /* Start working*/
    thread->start();

    // Очищаем ресурсы
    thread->quit();
    thread->wait();

//    Q_ASSERT(!wgt.data().isEmpty());

    return app.exec();

}

#include "main.moc"

Пытаюсь написать для него тест:
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>

#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        QThread::sleep(2); // имитируем долгий процесс вычислений в потоке
        emit resultReady("Workers are the best");
    }
signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &data);
};

class Client : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client() {}
    virtual ~Client() {}
    QString data() const;

public slots:
    void append(const QString& data) {
        m_data = data;
        qDebug() << " {" <<  data << "} ";
        std::cout << " [" <<  data.toStdString() << "] ";
    }

private:
    QString m_data;
};

QString Client::data() const {
    return m_data;
}

TEST(TimeOperatingTest, WorkIsHandledCorrectly) {

    int argc = 0;
    QCoreApplication app(argc, (char**)0);

    /* Setup thread */
    Client wgt;
    auto thread = new QThread(&wgt);
    auto worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, &wgt, &Client::append);

    /* Start working*/
    thread->start();


    // Очищаем ресурсы
    thread->quit();
    thread->wait();

    qDebug() << " wgt data " << wgt.data(); //  здесь пусто 

  //EXPECT_FALSE(wgt.data().isEmpty());

    app.exec();

    qDebug() << " wgt data " << wgt.data(); // суда естественно не дойдет 

}

#include "OperatingThreadTests.moc"


Подскажите как правильно тестировать QThread?

Вам надо не QThread тестировать, а проверить, что испускается нужный сигнал. Посмотрите в сторону QSignalSpy https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalspy.html#details
